# Extracting multiple groups out of a string?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract some information from a string as given below:

[Recently, ,, many, brane, inflation, scenarios, were, proposed, -LRB-, see, ,, e.g., ,, -LSB-, 3, -RSB-, for, a, review, -RRB-, ,, together, with, their, embeddings, into, the, -LRB-, warped, -RRB-, compactified, superstring, models, ,, in, a, good, package, with, the, phenomenological, constraints, coming, from, particle, physics, -LRB-, see, ,, e.g., ,, -LSB-, 4, -RSB-, -RRB-, .]

So what I need to extract is the values appearing between square braces 
(e.g. -LSB-, 3, -RSB-, && -LSB-, 4, -RSB-,)

Here is the related snippet of my code:

```
String pttrn = ".*-LSB-,\\s(\\d),\\s-RSB-,.*"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pttrn); 
m = pattern.matcher(sentence.toString()); rgx = m.find(); 
int count = 0;
while (rgx) {
    String ref = (m.group(1));             
    count++;
    System.out.println("found: " + count + " : " + m.start() + " - " + m.end());
    statement.clearParameters();
    statement.setString(1, rs.getString("ut"));
    statement.setString(2, rs.getString("sec_title"));  
    statement.setString(3, ref);
    statement.executeUpdate(); 

     }
```

As a result of this code, I always get one value. When I try m.group(2) I get an error saying there is no group 2.. What might I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one group within your Pattern, so a single match will only provide a single group. You need to apply the search multiple times:

```
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This means your code should be:

```
String input = "...";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("-LSB-,\\s(\\d),\\s-RSB-,").matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    // the real work should go here
}
```

For me this prints out:

```
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But now when I use m.find it again returns only one value. I am a bit confused. My pattern catches 2 same groups and by applying while(m.find()) i am anticipating to get them through the loop. OR should I write the same pattern again. If so I have to know how many groups exist in the sentence, before applying regex? Sorry for my poor explanation:(

Comment: Basically a single call to `m.find()` will find the regular expression once. That will then populate the `m.group(1)`. When you *call find again* the `m.group(1)` will be populated with _the next match_. The call `m.find()` returns a boolean indicating if the find was successful, so putting it in a while loop will search for every match. There is no need to know how many matches exist.

Comment: Basically you should replace `while (rgx)` with `while (m.find())` and remove the call to `m.find()` that is outside the while loop.

Comment: Ok so based on this explanation the simple loop :  while (m.find()) {  System.out.println(m.group(1)); } must give two outputs which are 3 and 4 considering the text I gave. But somehow I can only retriev the output 4. I think i am missing some small point.

Comment: Thank you very much. In my pattern I use .* in the beginning and end which hinders to get 3. By removing them as you did I get what i want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call find in your while loop:

```
  while (m.find()) {
```